# Android height width of all objest for all screen resolution

Tags: android, user-interface, user-experience, mobile-application

android height width of all object for all screen resolution of android devices :

for example:
240px
320px
480px etc.. devices have different resolution.
I need complete size list for all object like , button , icon, tab-bar, tab-bar-icon, top nav size, etc...

any one can help me ??
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: forget `px` when working with `Views` on Android. Here is the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) describing how to support different screen sizes, I highly suggest to consult this document before aiming to support different screens.

Regarding the sizes of UI components: [here you go](http://petrnohejl.github.io/Android-Cheatsheet-For-Graphic-Designers/), a very detailed description.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use for example dp (dip) instead of px. And look at the documentations that Droidman posted.